# Following multiple Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion

I just found this page today:

https://stackexchange.com/sites

and like many of the sites there and now I am a member of 18 of Stack Exchange sites. Now obviously it is a bad idea to think of opening all of them to ask/answer questions. Is there any way to have a shared home page for questions from all of them?

Comment: Did you try the other tabs on StackExchange.com?

Comment: No! What tabs?!

Comment: Ah, shame that I didn't notice it before! Could you please post an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: It might be wise to [keep this link for emergencies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-so).

Comment: Haha... yeah, it is addictive :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your request, I am re-submitting my comment as an answer.

Visit StackExchange and click on "tagged questions". There, you can create a "tag set", i.e. a collection of questions with certain tags (or just all questions) from any site of the network. E.g., you can add all questions from StackOverflow, questions tagged "grammar" from English Language and Usage, questions tagged "bug" from Board and Card Games Meta, and so on. Asterisks can be used as wildcards, e.g. "gnome*", "*architecture", or "*crypt*".

You can create several different tag sets. You can also browse the tag sets created by other people and/or save them to your tag sets.