# What term is appropriate to use to describe activity/engaging with others on SE user?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, terminology

If I were to describe myself as an active user, should I say "I'm a micro blogger at Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow"? Or is there a better term to use?

Comment: Somewhat related (not duplicate): *[How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-stack-overflow)* and *[What aspects of psychology does Stack Overflow take advantage of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56469)*.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q see my edit. I was just seeking for how to write about it on my profile at a different social media platform / resume / GitHub. Not sure why I got 6 downvotes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd avoid that term considering the site isn't a blog. Perhaps something like "active contributor" would be more fitting and that also nicely encompasses other activities you might perform like voting and reviewing the moderation queues.

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't think of such. So like "Active Contributor at StackOverflow"?

Comment: Yes that sounds good to me.